# How to programmatically check if particular daemon is runnning by specifying its name on Linux using C, C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

How to programmatically check if particular daemon is running by specifying its name on Linux using C, C++ ?

Comment: You should search systemd's documentation. But just for curiosity, is this a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)? From my experience when someone is asking this kind of question, they actually want to do something else.

Comment: Also, note that doing this can be a security risk because presumably the program would have to have root privileges in order to query the required data.

Comment: Maybe use something similar to this, and e.g. parse output of 'ps aux | grep <daemonname>': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix

Comment: Largely dependent on which init system you are running (SysV, systemd, runit, etc) - you may get more informed answers over on the [unix.se] site.

Answer (score 1):

A simple command to run would be `systemctl status ${service} | grep "Active:" | cut -d' ' -f6`. Capture the stdout of the above command and it should equal `(running)`.

On that note, `*ctl` are intended for command line use only and not for use by other programs. The accepted way is to interact with `systemd` using the `dbus` API.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot add comment above. 
you can use systemctl to check service status.

```
systemctl status servicename
```

This is terminal command. 
using `system("systemctl status servicename")` u can manage call from c++.

Hope this is what is were looking at or similar.

Comment: thanks!....Looks like in my CentOS this command is not available. its shows me following error:                                                  root@t1024rdb:~# systemctl
-sh: systemctl: command not found

Answer (score -2):

systemctl is-active ${service_name} can be used to check if a service is active or not